# how to delete a record using mongojs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am using mongojs together with nodejs and express. From so many online documents I only found `find()` `save()` `update()` methods.  Is there a `delete` api ? If so, how to use it?

I am trying to remove one record based on _id which is auto generated by mongdodb...

Any links and examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `remove` method.  From a quick look at the [source](https://github.com/gett/mongojs/blob/master/index.js) it looks like it's just a passthrough so it likely uses the same parameter conventions as the native node driver, so take a look at those [docs](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#remove).

Comment: I am trying to remove one record based on _id which is auto generated by mongdodb...it seems i need to do something extra in order to make it work...

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.remove(query, [justOne], [callback])
```

you can read the docs for monogojs https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs
for example To remove a single document from inventory, call the remove() method with the justOne parameter set to true or 1(default).
e.g

```
db.inventory.remove( { type : "food" }, callback)
```